# Generating <UL>

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a query result like this:

```
Top    Main    Sub
5   1024    10150
5   1024    10151
5   1024    10152
5   1025    10165
5   1025    10159
5   1025    10164
5   1025    10162
3   1011    10000
3   1011    10001
3   1011    10003
3   1013    10014
3   1013    10320
3   1013    10013
3   1012    10006
3   1012    10010
3   1012    10011
3   1012    10009
12  1087    10337
12  1087    10338
12  1087    10333
12  1087    10335
12  1087    10342
12  1087    10336
```

Now I want to make a dropdown menu. For that I need to create a `<UL>` `<LI>` list programatically, such as

```html
<ul>
  <li>5
    <ul>
      <li>1024
        <ul>
          <li>10150</li>
          <li>10151</li>
          <li>10152</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>1025
        <ul>
          <li>10165</li>
          <li>10159</li>
          <li>10164</li>
          <li>10162</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3
    <ul>
      <li>1011
        <ul>
          <li>10000</li>
          <li>10001</li>
          <li>10003</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>1013
        <ul>
          <li>10014</li>
          <li>10320</li>
          <li>10013</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>1012
        <ul>
          <li>10006</li>
          <li>10010</li>
          <li>10011</li>
          <li>10009</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>12
    <ul>
      <li>1087
        <ul>
          <li>10337</li>
          <li>10338</li>
          <li>10333</li>
          <li>10335</li>
          <li>10342</li>
          <li>10336</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This I want to create using VBScript/ASP, but trying since morning.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you, nor is it a replacement for a VBScript tutorial. There are lots of examples for generating HTML elements with VBScript here, so try to come up with something yourself, and come back when you have a specific question about something in your code (show your code!) that you can't get to work.

Comment: The problem in my opinion is with the result of the query itself. You should group by main and have all the subs in the same field. If you're using mysql db check the `group_concat` function